# I want to sort date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables
chat_room have two columns : id, slogan
chat have 3 columns : id, chat_room_id,updated_at

this is my code

```
SELECT chat_room.*
FROM chat_room
ORDER BY (SELECT updated_at FROM chat WHERE chat.chat_room_id = chat_room.id ) DESC;
```

this is my bug
SELECT chat_room.* FROM chat_room ORDER BY (SELECT updated_at FROM chat WHERE chat.chat_room_id = chat_room.id) DESC LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row  0.00058 sec

Comment: I have done from the help bellow

Comment: Are you sure you accepted the correct answer?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not.  The accepted answer isn't even the same result set.  But, maybe the OP still accepts it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it better to do a join instead of using a subquery and achieve what you want like this:

```
SELECT
cr.*
FROM chat_room cr
JOIN chat c on cr.id=c.chat_room_id
order by updated_at desc
```

Comment: ...maybe, but keep in mind your answer will produce a different result set.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause sometimes is returning more than one record.  This raises the question of *which* `updated_at` value you want to use in the case that a given chat room might have more than one value.  Assuming you want to sort by the *latest* `updated_at` value, you could use:

```sql
SELECT cr.*
FROM chat_room cr
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT chat_room_id, MAX(updated_at) AS max_updated_at
    FROM chat
    GROUP BY chat_room_id
) c
    ON c.chat_room_id = cr.id
ORDER BY
    c.max_updated_at DESC;
```